# Get and update plist value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a plist titled "appData.plist" in my supporting files section of Xcode.  I have a key called "keyone" and am trying to get the value of it.  I'm trying to log the value to console with NSLog but its not working.

How do you do this?  I've searched google and there are a lot of way but none work for me.

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"appData" ofType: @"plist"];
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
NSString *viewCover = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"keyone"];
```

This is what i've tried but the whole thing ends in errors, I can't log it and I get an 'unusable variable' error.

Comment: Is your `appData.plist` file properly added to your target and being copied correctly?

Comment: Why are you getting the value of ```keyone``` from the info dictionary? Wouldn't you want ```NSString *viewCover = [myDict objectForKey:@"keyone"];```?

Comment: Sorry this is one of my first times with ios but what do you mean by added to target?  Everything is spelt correctly if thats what you mean by copied correctly.

Comment: The value i'm getting is a Boolean value

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I'm not sure if your last comment was in response to me...

Comment: gtmtg: I did and it works perfectly if I were to be using a string in my plist.  But I am using a boolean and need to know if it is YES or NO.  SO I take it my mistake is that it should not be NSString *viewCover.  Then how do I log that?

Comment: See my answer. By the way, you tag people by putting an @ sign in front of their username :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` method retrieves a value from your app's `Info.plist` file, which isn't what you want -- you want to retreive it from your dictionary `myDict`. You mentioned that the value is actually a boolean, so replace the last line with

```
BOOL viewCover = [[myDict objectForKey:@"keyOne"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Great now how do I log that to console?

Comment: NSLog(viewCover ? @"YES": @"NO");    ?

Comment: Oh I had a typo, fixed comment above, Thank you